# Can Visual studio 2013 Pro Connect to Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

We are going to buy "VS 2013 Pro" and we need to know, if this product is compatible with tfs 2010 version. Are they able to connect properly. Maybe somebody tried or found an official post from microsoft about support.

Comment: Your title says TFS 2010, but your post says TFS 2013, which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially yes, TFS 2010 or higher supports VS 2013, but I have found you can get the following:

"You cannot connect to {IP Address here} because it is running a version of Team Foundation Server that is not supported by your version of Visual Studio" blah blah blah

If you get this, you may have to mess around with your Team Explorer version to get one that is compatible with TFS 2010. I have not experimented with the standard Visual Studio plug in. I do know that you can also download the MSSCCI client bits and switch to them in options if you are still having issues.

This pix shows switching to the MSSCCCI client: 
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GYFtUDIlZcg/UI1jVHwlaaI/AAAAAAAAVgQ/lVKlW_Mc-XU/s400/Select+Source+Control.png

Comment: Does this mean I wont be able to use VS integrated TFS client  when using the [MSSCCI plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8) and use only Team Explorer like old days  if I need to connect to TFS2010 from VS 2013 ?

Answer (score 2):

See [Compatibility between Team Foundation clients and Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx)

Comment: I would note the compatibility link does not answer the question in this case. It does not show how to connect a newer client with an older version of the server.

Comment: Can you summarize the information from the link that specifically answers this question?